# Gallery Thumbnail Layout Template

Tags: attachments, gallery

Is there a way to create a template to display a gallery thumb layout?

Or am I stuck with selecting a thumbnail size and rows in the upload image/gallery area and media settings area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the better approaches is to unregister WP's default gallery shortcode function, and add your own customized replacement.  WP engineer has a great post about it [here](http://wpengineer.com/1802/a-solution-for-the-wordpress-gallery/). This also will let you fix that  funky inline CSS that the default gallery adds to the page.